# Java-RegEx: How to find number followed by space without having colon

Tags: java, regex

I have below string for one scenario it shows ":" colon and other scenario colon is not displayed. I need to capture the number followed by the string. I have written regex to capture number followed by ":" colon. Please let me know How I can write RegEx which don't have colon

String: 

**Your authentication code is 19930 to add TestUser as beneficiary for payment from your account. If you have not requested to add this beneficiary, please contact the bank IMMEDIATELY on 00971 600 54 0000**

*Your authentication code is: 58738 to pay AED 500.00 to Emicool through online/mobile banking. Please do not share this code with any person. If you have not requested any payment, please contact the bank IMMEDIATELY on 00971 600 54 0000 .*

The bold paragraph don't have colon after word "is" and the italic paragraph have colon.

Code I have written for capturing number after color

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver1.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr"));
            for (WebElement row : rows)
            {
                String text = row.getText();
                if (text.contains(mobilenumber))
                {
                   String regex = ": (\\d+)"; //Your authentication code is


                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

                    if (matcher.find())             
                         {

                        valueis = matcher.group(1); 
                        System.out.println(valueis);

                        break;
```

I have the above messages captured in a table and when I use "?:(\d+)" the phone number is captured but not the five digits.

```
<tr bgcolor="#EBD8B8"> 

<td align="left" nowrap><font face="times new roman" size=3 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;00955555555555</font></td>
<td align="left" nowrap><font face="times new roman" size=3 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2017-04-17 14:24:37.257</font></td>
<td align="left"><font face="times new roman" size=3 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your authentication code is  28201 to add name as beneficiary for payment from your account. If you have not requested to add this beneficiary, please contact the bank
```

IMMEDIATELY on 00971 600 54 0000.

```
<td align="left" nowrap><font face="times new roman" size=3 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;00955111111111</font></td>
<td align="left" nowrap><font face="times new roman" size=3 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2017-04-17 14:16:19.243</font></td>
<td align="left"><font face="times new roman" size=3 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Your new Online and Mobile Banking application authentication code is 81419. Please do not share this code with any person.   To complete the process, please visit www.emiratesnbd.com, click on Register Online/Forgot User ID or Password, click on Forgot User ID or Password. Thank you.</font></td>
<tr>
```

Comment: You want to capture numbers if they are after a `:` and nothing else?

Comment: I have captured the five digit numbers after capture and I wanna capture fivie digit numbers after text without colon

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong. You need two patterns: **one for digits not after `:`** and **one for digits after `:`** Am I right? or not?

Comment: @Sowmya: Anrei's https://regex101.com/r/TpPL6f/2 should work for both 
 cases.

Comment: yes k-five you are right

Comment: Okay. Well do you need **only those digits** or not? you need **the entire of the paragraph** to be match?

Comment: I will have multiple rows and matching with mobile number xxxx and if it matches then reading and matching with pattern. and need to get the 5 digit code.

Comment: Please see the code I have written which works well because I have used : as delimiter and also the <tr> rows

Comment: Sorry it does not make sense to me. Also when you comment to someone use `@` before its name to call that person to see your comment. like `@k-five`

Comment: @k-five thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the colon optional by using the `?` operator

https://regexone.com/lesson/optional_characters (maybe this is helpfull)

Regex:

```
":? (\\d+)"
```

Update: added lookahead [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/TpPL6f/1)

/(?=(Your authentication code is:?))\1 (\d+)/gm

Or even simpler withouth the lookahead: [DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/TpPL6f/2) Use the Capture Group 1 to get the number

```
/Your authentication code is:? (\d+)/gm
```

Comment: In that case it would also match `00971`, `600`, `54` and `0000`, which is not what the OP needs to achieve

Comment: hmm in that case we could add a lookahead something like this: "(?=Your authentication code is):? (\\d+)"

Comment: No, you'd need a lookbehind.

Comment: you are right I mainly work with javascript and we don't have lookbehinds there so we need to improvise :) Updated the Answer

Comment: @AndreiVoicu Even if you linked to regex101, you should post the two updated regexes inside the answer, otherwise if the links on regex101 die this answer would become useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\D*(\d+)
```

Maybe this can help you .

Comment: Please, don't post link only answer.